# Multiple DAGs run on Airflow 2.0 unintentionally at a time

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I installed Airflow with postgreSQL for the first time.
However, after activating DAG on the web, about 16 DAGs are created at the same time as shown in the picture below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E24Cv.png)

As a test, I made a dag that enters the current date into the db for 10 seconds once a second. If intended, it should be generated one row per second, but the problem above creates multiple rows per second.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgvkh.png)

Below is the DAG code.

```
import pendulum
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

kst = pendulum.timezone("Asia/Seoul")

args = {'owner': 'jovyan', 'start_date': datetime(2021, 5, 3, 16,20,10, tzinfo=kst), 'run_as_user':'bskim'}
#args = {'owner': 'jovyan', 'start_date': days_ago(n=1)}
dag  = DAG(dag_id='talend_first_dag',
        default_args=args,
        schedule_interval='0/1 * * * *')

talend_command = "/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS_run.sh "

t1 = BashOperator(task_id='talend_first',
                bash_command=talend_command,
                dag=dag)


t1
```

Below is result "ps-ef |grep airflow".

```
(venv) [bskim@swproduct airflow_home]$ ps -ef |grep airflow
bskim    108569 103922  2 17:23 pts/0    00:00:30 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow webserver
bskim    108607 108569  0 17:23 pts/0    00:00:01 gunicorn: master [airflow-webserver]
bskim    109264 103922  2 17:28 pts/0    00:00:25 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109266 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109274 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109275 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109276 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109277 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109278 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109280 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109281 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109282 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109283 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109285 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109286 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109287 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109288 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109290 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109291 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109292 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109293 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109294 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109296 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109297 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109298 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109300 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109301 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109302 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109303 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109304 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109306 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109307 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109308 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109310 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109311 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109312 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow scheduler
bskim    109313 109264  0 17:28 pts/0    00:00:02 airflow scheduler -- DagFileProcessorManager
bskim    110825 108607  1 17:36 pts/0    00:00:05 [ready] gunicorn: worker [airflow-webserver]
bskim    110921 108607  1 17:36 pts/0    00:00:05 [ready] gunicorn: worker [airflow-webserver]
bskim    111012 108607  1 17:37 pts/0    00:00:05 [ready] gunicorn: worker [airflow-webserver]
bskim    111109 108607  1 17:37 pts/0    00:00:05 [ready] gunicorn: worker [airflow-webserver]
bskim    112652 109310  0 17:41 pts/0    00:00:00 airflow task supervisor: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'talend_idx_2_dag', 'talend_idx_2', '2021-05-03T09:26:00+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--subdir', '/home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_idx_2.py']
bskim    112729 109312  0 17:41 pts/0    00:00:00 airflow task supervisor: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'talend_idx_2_dag', 'talend_idx_2', '2021-05-03T09:27:00+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--subdir', '/home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_idx_2.py']
bskim    112754 112652  1 17:41 ?        00:00:01 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow tasks run talend_idx_2_dag talend_idx_2 2021-05-03T09:26:00+00:00 --job-id 448 --pool default_pool --raw --subdir /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_idx_2.py --cfg-path /tmp/tmpepxvlj4v --error-file /tmp/tmpupd5hmkg
bskim    112781 112729  1 17:41 ?        00:00:01 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow tasks run talend_idx_2_dag talend_idx_2 2021-05-03T09:27:00+00:00 --job-id 449 --pool default_pool --raw --subdir /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_idx_2.py --cfg-path /tmp/tmp2kswizo1 --error-file /tmp/tmpiifxr0x7
bskim    112981 109276  0 17:42 pts/0    00:00:00 airflow task supervisor: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'talend_first_dag', 'talend_first', '2021-05-03T10:43:00+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--subdir', '/home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_first.py']
bskim    113052 109277  0 17:42 pts/0    00:00:00 airflow task supervisor: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'talend_first_dag', 'talend_first', '2021-05-03T10:44:00+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--subdir', '/home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_first.py']
bskim    113055 112981  2 17:42 ?        00:00:01 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow tasks run talend_first_dag talend_first 2021-05-03T10:43:00+00:00 --job-id 450 --pool default_pool --raw --subdir /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_first.py --cfg-path /tmp/tmppkeav48n --error-file /tmp/tmp920t73mg
bskim    113065 108607  3 17:42 pts/0    00:00:02 gunicorn: worker [airflow-webserver]
bskim    113090 109274  0 17:42 pts/0    00:00:00 airflow task supervisor: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'talend_first_dag', 'talend_first', '2021-05-03T10:45:00+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--subdir', '/home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_first.py']
bskim    113121 113052  2 17:42 ?        00:00:01 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow tasks run talend_first_dag talend_first 2021-05-03T10:44:00+00:00 --job-id 451 --pool default_pool --raw --subdir /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_first.py --cfg-path /tmp/tmphhj4r3oh --error-file /tmp/tmpa8ad955w
bskim    113162 109275  0 17:42 pts/0    00:00:00 airflow task supervisor: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'talend_first_dag', 'talend_first', '2021-05-03T10:46:00+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--subdir', '/home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_first.py']
bskim    113168 113090  2 17:42 ?        00:00:01 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow tasks run talend_first_dag talend_first 2021-05-03T10:45:00+00:00 --job-id 452 --pool default_pool --raw --subdir /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_first.py --cfg-path /tmp/tmp_vhz10e0 --error-file /tmp/tmpsgh_rus8
bskim    113199 109278  0 17:42 pts/0    00:00:00 airflow task supervisor: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'talend_first_dag', 'talend_first', '2021-05-03T10:47:00+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--subdir', '/home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_first.py']
bskim    113200 113162  2 17:42 ?        00:00:01 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow tasks run talend_first_dag talend_first 2021-05-03T10:46:00+00:00 --job-id 453 --pool default_pool --raw --subdir /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_first.py --cfg-path /tmp/tmpy3rssjwn --error-file /tmp/tmp39hnh9o1
bskim    113286 109280  0 17:42 pts/0    00:00:00 airflow task supervisor: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'talend_idx_2_dag', 'talend_idx_2', '2021-05-03T09:28:00+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--subdir', '/home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_idx_2.py']
bskim    113287 109285  0 17:42 pts/0    00:00:00 airflow task supervisor: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'talend_first_dag', 'talend_first', '2021-05-03T10:48:00+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--subdir', '/home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_first.py']
bskim    113288 113199  3 17:42 ?        00:00:01 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow tasks run talend_first_dag talend_first 2021-05-03T10:47:00+00:00 --job-id 454 --pool default_pool --raw --subdir /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_first.py --cfg-path /tmp/tmpo1_l0dct --error-file /tmp/tmpe0ynvaaa
bskim    113299 109281  0 17:43 pts/0    00:00:00 airflow task supervisor: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'talend_idx_2_dag', 'talend_idx_2', '2021-05-03T09:29:00+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--subdir', '/home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_idx_2.py']
bskim    113300 109283  0 17:43 pts/0    00:00:00 airflow task supervisor: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'talend_first_dag', 'talend_first', '2021-05-03T10:49:00+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--subdir', '/home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_first.py']
bskim    113301 113286  3 17:43 ?        00:00:01 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow tasks run talend_idx_2_dag talend_idx_2 2021-05-03T09:28:00+00:00 --job-id 456 --pool default_pool --raw --subdir /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_idx_2.py --cfg-path /tmp/tmpblx5vzdt --error-file /tmp/tmpbzp5s9st
bskim    113303 113287  3 17:43 ?        00:00:01 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow tasks run talend_first_dag talend_first 2021-05-03T10:48:00+00:00 --job-id 455 --pool default_pool --raw --subdir /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_first.py --cfg-path /tmp/tmpawabzixj --error-file /tmp/tmpr4rau1_t
bskim    113331 109286  1 17:43 pts/0    00:00:00 airflow task supervisor: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'talend_idx_2_dag', 'talend_idx_2', '2021-05-03T09:30:00+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--subdir', '/home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_idx_2.py']
bskim    113332 109282  1 17:43 pts/0    00:00:00 airflow task supervisor: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'talend_first_dag', 'talend_first', '2021-05-03T10:50:00+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--subdir', '/home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_first.py']
bskim    113334 113300  3 17:43 ?        00:00:01 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow tasks run talend_first_dag talend_first 2021-05-03T10:49:00+00:00 --job-id 457 --pool default_pool --raw --subdir /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_first.py --cfg-path /tmp/tmppn54vxqi --error-file /tmp/tmpc36akon7
bskim    113336 113299  3 17:43 ?        00:00:01 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow tasks run talend_idx_2_dag talend_idx_2 2021-05-03T09:29:00+00:00 --job-id 458 --pool default_pool --raw --subdir /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_idx_2.py --cfg-path /tmp/tmpffxckf4j --error-file /tmp/tmpqnx2vdom
bskim    113347 113332  3 17:43 ?        00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow tasks run talend_first_dag talend_first 2021-05-03T10:50:00+00:00 --job-id 459 --pool default_pool --raw --subdir /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_first.py --cfg-path /tmp/tmphexft182 --error-file /tmp/tmpq0_wfubu
bskim    113348 113331  3 17:43 ?        00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow tasks run talend_idx_2_dag talend_idx_2 2021-05-03T09:30:00+00:00 --job-id 460 --pool default_pool --raw --subdir /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_idx_2.py --cfg-path /tmp/tmpxp7m7131 --error-file /tmp/tmp7qpmc7kp
bskim    113351 109288  1 17:43 pts/0    00:00:00 airflow task supervisor: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'talend_idx_2_dag', 'talend_idx_2', '2021-05-03T09:31:00+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--subdir', '/home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_idx_2.py']
bskim    113352 109287  1 17:43 pts/0    00:00:00 airflow task supervisor: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'talend_first_dag', 'talend_first', '2021-05-03T10:51:00+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--subdir', '/home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_first.py']
bskim    113366 113360  6 17:43 ?        00:00:01 java -Dtalend.component.manager.m2.repository=/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib -Xms256M -Xmx1024M -cp .:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/routines.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.12.1.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/log4j-api-2.12.1.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/log4j-core-2.12.1.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/postgresql-42.2.9.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/crypto-utils.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/dom4j-2.1.1.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/airflow_test_insert_dummy_rows_0_1.jar: test.airflow_test_insert_dummy_rows_0_1.AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS --context=Dev
bskim    113376 109290  1 17:43 pts/0    00:00:00 airflow task supervisor: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'talend_idx_2_dag', 'talend_idx_2', '2021-05-03T09:32:00+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--subdir', '/home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_idx_2.py']
bskim    113381 113352  3 17:43 ?        00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow tasks run talend_first_dag talend_first 2021-05-03T10:51:00+00:00 --job-id 461 --pool default_pool --raw --subdir /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_first.py --cfg-path /tmp/tmpg2lyaeig --error-file /tmp/tmpvpcv2k_d
bskim    113382 113351  3 17:43 ?        00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow tasks run talend_idx_2_dag talend_idx_2 2021-05-03T09:31:00+00:00 --job-id 462 --pool default_pool --raw --subdir /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_idx_2.py --cfg-path /tmp/tmp62kc8itw --error-file /tmp/tmpvhebo3kj
bskim    113401 113398  6 17:43 ?        00:00:00 java -Dtalend.component.manager.m2.repository=/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib -Xms256M -Xmx1024M -cp .:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/routines.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.12.1.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/log4j-api-2.12.1.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/log4j-core-2.12.1.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/postgresql-42.2.9.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/crypto-utils.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/dom4j-2.1.1.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/airflow_test_insert_dummy_rows_0_1.jar: test.airflow_test_insert_dummy_rows_0_1.AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS --context=Dev
bskim    113449 109293  1 17:43 pts/0    00:00:00 airflow task supervisor: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'talend_idx_2_dag', 'talend_idx_2', '2021-05-03T09:33:00+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--subdir', '/home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_idx_2.py']
bskim    113450 109291  2 17:43 pts/0    00:00:00 airflow task supervisor: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'talend_first_dag', 'talend_first', '2021-05-03T10:52:00+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--subdir', '/home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_first.py']
bskim    113462 113376  3 17:43 ?        00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow tasks run talend_idx_2_dag talend_idx_2 2021-05-03T09:32:00+00:00 --job-id 463 --pool default_pool --raw --subdir /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_idx_2.py --cfg-path /tmp/tmpj3908y63 --error-file /tmp/tmp7e2vqj77
bskim    113468 113464  6 17:43 ?        00:00:00 java -Dtalend.component.manager.m2.repository=/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib -Xms256M -Xmx1024M -cp .:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/routines.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.12.1.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/log4j-api-2.12.1.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/log4j-core-2.12.1.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/postgresql-42.2.9.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/crypto-utils.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/dom4j-2.1.1.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/airflow_test_insert_dummy_rows_0_1.jar: test.airflow_test_insert_dummy_rows_0_1.AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS --context=Dev
bskim    113483 109292  2 17:43 pts/0    00:00:00 airflow task supervisor: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'talend_idx_2_dag', 'talend_idx_2', '2021-05-03T09:34:00+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--subdir', '/home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_idx_2.py']
bskim    113484 109300  2 17:43 pts/0    00:00:00 airflow task supervisor: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'talend_first_dag', 'talend_first', '2021-05-03T10:53:00+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--subdir', '/home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_first.py']
bskim    113488 113449  3 17:43 ?        00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow tasks run talend_idx_2_dag talend_idx_2 2021-05-03T09:33:00+00:00 --job-id 464 --pool default_pool --raw --subdir /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_idx_2.py --cfg-path /tmp/tmp2d7zszd2 --error-file /tmp/tmpxhrfjto_
bskim    113490 113450  3 17:43 ?        00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow tasks run talend_first_dag talend_first 2021-05-03T10:52:00+00:00 --job-id 465 --pool default_pool --raw --subdir /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_first.py --cfg-path /tmp/tmp05cgdqd1 --error-file /tmp/tmpv8x5_4lc
bskim    113497 113491  5 17:43 ?        00:00:00 java -Dtalend.component.manager.m2.repository=/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib -Xms256M -Xmx1024M -cp .:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/routines.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.12.1.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/log4j-api-2.12.1.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/log4j-core-2.12.1.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/postgresql-42.2.9.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/crypto-utils.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/dom4j-2.1.1.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/airflow_test_insert_dummy_rows_0_1.jar: test.airflow_test_insert_dummy_rows_0_1.AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS --context=Dev
bskim    113513 109294  3 17:43 pts/0    00:00:00 airflow task supervisor: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'talend_idx_2_dag', 'talend_idx_2', '2021-05-03T09:35:00+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--subdir', '/home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_idx_2.py']
bskim    113514 109296  4 17:43 pts/0    00:00:00 airflow task supervisor: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'talend_first_dag', 'talend_first', '2021-05-03T10:54:00+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--subdir', '/home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_first.py']
bskim    113515 113483  4 17:43 ?        00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow tasks run talend_idx_2_dag talend_idx_2 2021-05-03T09:34:00+00:00 --job-id 466 --pool default_pool --raw --subdir /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_idx_2.py --cfg-path /tmp/tmpmmkwhfic --error-file /tmp/tmpi5wzbio8
bskim    113518 113484  4 17:43 ?        00:00:00 /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/python /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/venv/bin/airflow tasks run talend_first_dag talend_first 2021-05-03T10:53:00+00:00 --job-id 467 --pool default_pool --raw --subdir /home/bskim/dev/airflow/workspace/airflow_home/dags/talend_first.py --cfg-path /tmp/tmp1b9oaxu0 --error-file /tmp/tmpyxqlwzvs
bskim    113532 113529  4 17:43 ?        00:00:00 java -Dtalend.component.manager.m2.repository=/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib -Xms256M -Xmx1024M -cp .:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/routines.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.12.1.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/log4j-api-2.12.1.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/log4j-core-2.12.1.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/postgresql-42.2.9.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/crypto-utils.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/../lib/dom4j-2.1.1.jar:/home/bskim/dev/temp/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS/airflow_test_insert_dummy_rows_0_1.jar: test.airflow_test_insert_dummy_rows_0_1.AIRFLOW_TEST_INSERT_DUMMY_ROWS --context=Dev
bskim    113535 103922  0 17:43 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto airflow
```

The executor is LocalExecutor, and even if it is set to SequentialExecutor, the result is the same.

I wasted two days because of this problem. I need your help!

Comment: This question isn't clear and very broad. Please focus your question and post the DAG code that you are asking about. The behavior is a result of a code if you don't share a code we can't help you.

Comment: All right. Give me five minutes.

Comment: You are getting many runs because your start_date is in the past and you didn't add catchup = False

Comment: Wow!!! You are my Savior!!! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Airflow has a default True value for [catchup_by_default](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/d295e708d982082caa68b08ab29c8aa4bf67dce5/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L891) setting so if you didn't change the defaults you must specify `catchup=False` in your DAGs if you don't want them to backfill runs from the given `start_date`.

```
dag  = DAG(dag_id='talend_first_dag',
        default_args=args,
        schedule_interval='0/1 * * * *',
        catchup=False)
```

Another possible solution (assuming you need `catchup`) is not to set the `start_date` in the past.